# C# change a string variable with List or Array

Tags: c#, list

I have some static strings

```
static string   Robocopy_Mirror = "[Robocopy_Mirror]"; 
static string   Robocopy_Copy = "[Robocopy_Copy]";
static string   Network_Path_1 = "[Network_Path_1]";    // \\NAS\Sync\
static string   Lokal_Path_1 = "[Lokal_Path_1]";      // X:\Sync\
```

And I thought I could save some lines of code if I put them in a List and change the values in the List with a loop.

```
List<string> variableListe = new List<string>()  
{   
    Robocopy_Mirror , Robocopy_Copy , Network_Path_1, Lokal_Path_1, 
    File_Network_Sync_1, File_Lokal_Sync_1, File_Network_Sync_2, File_Lokal_Sync_2
};
```

But I can't change the static variables. I guess the List object does not change the static variable? Is there a quick way to change it?

```
for (int i = 0; i < variableListe.Count-1; i++)
{
    variableListe[i] = AppConfig.ElementAt(configPathPosition);
}
Console.WriteLine(Robocopy_Mirror); 

// prints  "[Robocopy_Mirror]" instead of like C:\robocopy
```

Comment: Code should work if "AppConfig.ElementAt(configPathPosition)" is a string, 
 if configPathPosition is a number, and new value is different from original value.

Comment: Maybe you could use a Dictionary<string, string>, using your statics as keys and appConfig info as values.

Comment: You haven't really saved any lines of code though, in fact what you have done is make the code harder to read and work with. For structured data like this you might consider making an object to pass them as a single reference but hard to tell if this is necessary with this small amount of code

Answer (score 2):

The static variables store references to string objects in memory. The elements in the list also store references to the same string objects in memory, but *each element is it's own variable* and those elements *do not store references to the static variables;* they refer to the string objects directly.

When you change an element in the list, you're changing the variable in the list to point to a new object in a new memory location. The static variables do not change and continue to refer to the same unchanged strings as they did before.